# div without fixed width to bypass parent with fixed width

Tags: css, html, fixed-width

Please consider my problem, I want to make series of images to behave just like non breaking text,

**parent element** - It may be any element, It may or may not have a fixed width, so basically I cannot apply any css to it. In most cases it is a "td" tag.

**child div** - This should behave like a word, fixed width cannot be determined, but has a fixed height as Image height, css can be applied.

**Image** - This should behave like a character in a word, has fixed width & same fixed height as of child div.

This is a normal Box Model behavior of html elements, with texts inside an element having fixed width.

|=======parent element========|
| Some breaking text with spaces   |
| in between.                                   |
|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**|

This is a condition which cannot be avoided and forces the parent to increase its fixed width.

|==============parent element===========|
| |=============child div ===============| |
| |SomeUnbreakingLongWordHavingNoSpaces| |
| |***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**| |
|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**|

I want my images with no spaces in between to behave the same way but it behaves something like this,

|=======parent element========|
| |=========child div =========| |
| | |Image| |Image| |Image| |Image|   | |
| | |Image| |Image|                          | |
| |***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**| |
|**__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**|

the images and the child div are having a fixed height, so basically any extra element should be pushed horizontally to the right, but it does not, please share your solutions regarding this problem.

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works, but try add `width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;` to child-div, and `float: left;` to images.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [mock-up](http://tinkerbin.com/Von5aiYL)
The **word-wrap** style property will use to break the words/content
Apply style `word-wrap:break-word;` to child div.